# Is there a way to download only a subdirectory from git?

Tags: git, download

Is there a way to download only a given subdirectory from a git repository? Say I want to fetch only the `nyancat` directory from https://github.com/djdeath/toys.git .

I could either clone the whole repository and ignore the files I don't want, or go to https://github.com/djdeath/toys/tree/master/nyancat and download the relevant files one by one. I think there must be an easier way.

Note I'm not asking if it is possible to *clone* the directory, this was [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-git-repositorys-sub-directory-only) and is apparently not possible. I'm just interested in quickly getting the files, and don't need to commit back, or use git on them again.

Comment: The lack of this ability is the worst thing about git.

Answer (score 2):

The [`git-archive`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html) command will do pretty much what you want, but it needs to operate on an already cloned repo, so if you've got SSH access to the host, you can do:

```
cd /path/to/destination
ssh user@host "cd /path/to/repo && git archive HEAD dir/you/want" | tar xf -
```

Or, with compression for the network transport:

```
cd /path/to/destination
ssh user@host "cd /path/to/repo && git archive HEAD dir/you/want | gzip" | tar xzf -
```

Answer (score 1):

## A full paramateric bash function (no-dependancy)

```sh
#!/bin/bash

gitsub() {

  usage() {
        cat <<- EOF
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        GNU gitsub 0.0.1, a non-interactive github filtered subrepo retriever.
        Usage: gitsub [-h] [[-d[dir] -s[strip] -e[ext]] -o owner -r repo -b sub]
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        MANDATORY:
          -o, --owner           repo's owner
          -r, --repo            repo's name
          -b, --subrepo         directory(s) to be cloned
        OPTIONS:
          -s, --strip           number of dirs (/) to be skipped, default 0
          -d, --dir             output directory default current directory
          -e, --extension       filter by ext, if missing clone all (including subdirs)
        COMMANDS:
          -h, --help            display this help and exit
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Mail bug reports and suggestions to makramjandar@gmail.com
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        EOF
  }

  error() { echo -e "\033[1;31mError: $1\033[0m" ;}

  # check supplied args
  is_arg() { 
    [[ -n "$2" && ${2:0:1} != "-" ]] \
    || { error "Argument for $1 is missing..." >&2 \
    && usage \
    && exit 1 ;}
  }

  POSITIONAL=()
  while (( "$#" )); do
    case "$1" in
      # commands
      -h|--help)      usage && exit 0                                    ;;
      # mandatory flags with arguments
      -o|--owner)     is_arg $1 $2 && OWNER=$2                 ; shift 2 ;;
      -r|--repo)      is_arg $1 $2 && REPO=$2                  ; shift 2 ;;
      -b|--subrepo)   is_arg $1 $2 && SUBREPO=$2               ; shift 2 ;;
      # optional flags with arguments
      -d|--dir)       is_arg $1 $2 && DIR=$2 && mkdir -p $DIR  ; shift 2 ;;
      -s|--strip)     is_arg $1 $2 && STRIP=$2                 ; shift 2 ;;
      -e|--extension) is_arg $1 $2 && EXTENSION=$2             ; shift 2 ;;
      # unsupported flags 
      -*|--*=) error "Unsupported flag $1" >&2 && usage        ; exit 1  ;;
      # preserve positional arguments
      *) POSITIONAL+=("$1")                                    ; shift   ;;
    esac
  done
  # set positional arguments in their proper place
  set -- "${POSITIONAL[@]}"

  # check mandatory arguments
  [[ -z "$OWNER" || -z "$REPO" || -z "$SUBREPO" ]] \
  && { error "Missing mandatory arguments..." >&2 \
  && usage \
  && exit 1 ;}

  # get github filtered (optional) subrepository
  {
    curl -L "https://api.github.com/repos/$OWNER/$REPO/tarball" \
    | 
      tar \
      --verbose \
      --extract \
      --gzip \
      --directory=${DIR:-$PWD} \
      --strip=${STRIP:-0} \
      --wildcards */${SUBREPO}/*.${EXTENSION}*
  } 2>/dev/null \
    && echo "Done" \
    || \
  { 
    error "Invalid args..." \
    && usage \
    && exit 1
  }
}

gitsub "$@"
```

For a given repo: https://github.com/jenskutilek/free-fonts

To download the entire contents of the sub-folder Fira including dirs and files

```sh
$ bash gitsub.sh -o "jenskutilek" -r "free-fonts" -b "Fira" -d "FiraUnfiltered" -s 2

$ tree -d FiraUnfiltered/
FiraUnfiltered/
├── Fira Mono
│   ├── OTF
│   ├── TTF
│   ├── VFB
│   └── WOFF
└── Fira Sans
    ├── OTF
    ├── TTF
    ├── VFB
    └── WOFF
```

To downlod the same subfolder but filtered with the font TTF

```sh
$ bash gitsub.sh -o "jenskutilek" -r "free-fonts" -b "Fira" -d "FiraFiltered" -s 2 -e "ttf"

$ tree -d FiraFiltered/
FiraFiltered/
├── Fira Mono
│   └── TTF
└── Fira Sans
    └── TTF
```

downlod only the filtered files to the outdir by setting -s|--strip to 4

```sh
bash gitsub.sh -o "jenskutilek" -r "free-fonts" -b "Fira" -d "ttfFilesOnly" -s 4 -e "ttf"

$ tree ttfFilesOnly/
ttfFilesOnly/
├── FiraMono-Bold.ttf
├── FiraMono-Regular.ttf
├── FiraSans-Bold.ttf
├── FiraSans-BoldItalic.ttf
├── FiraSans-Light.ttf
├── FiraSans-LightItalic.ttf
├── FiraSans-Medium.ttf
├── FiraSans-MediumItalic.ttf
├── FiraSans-Regular.ttf
└── FiraSans-RegularItalic.ttf
```

Comment: You should explain your script a bit.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: My function is provided with an embeded help... shall I print it or must I rewrite a second help for the help itself !! A bit of consistency, please Sir

Comment: @Ale I had mean to edit the answer, not to add a comment adding details for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I just [wrote a script](https://github.com/mfbx9da4/git-sub-dir)

usage

```
      python get_git_sub_dir.py path/to/sub/dir <RECURSIVE>
```