# git clone https://username@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git certain folder contents into /public_html on server

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am trying to close a repository but only want to grab the contents of the folder /SOURCE/* from the remote repository and pull the contents of that folder into /public_html/* so SOURCE/* into public_html/*

Remote repo root is folder structured as has other folders like backups etc... but I just need to checkout / clone the content of SOURCE as all the web files into desired folder on server.

It is a BitBucket repo which is Git (of course); I have been reading up and trying to work out how to do it, but not having any luck.

If it is not possible then all good, I'll just manually zip and upload, but I thought if can do via Git would be easier to update the code on the site via Git for changes on repo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to download only a subdirectory from git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239055/is-there-a-way-to-download-only-a-subdirectory-from-git)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+download+subdirectory